# How can we detect location without GPS or WiFi?

Tags: android, gps, location, android-wifi, locationmanager

We have an interesting use case where the intended device does not have GPS embedded in it. Nor will it be connected to any cell towers.

The only connection the device has to the outside world is through the web. But there is a high probability that the network  location is in different city showing the wrong address...for example user is in CA but the network being accessed is located in MI (thus showing the user's location in MI).

Does the Android SDK contain an API that can serve as a workaround to this scenario?

Comment: I dont understand, if the device is in CA how would it think its in MI?

Comment: From my experience, Location data returned from network Listeners will be a 500 meters approximate value. To get more accurate value, we need GPS listeners.

Comment: @tyczj : the usage of proxy servers would cause the ip address to be shown in a different location.

Answer (score 1):

IP Geolocation should work, unless when you say "network being accessed" you mean that the Android device creates a VPN tunnel to MI.

[The Google Maps Geolocation API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/business/geolocation/) will also work off of wifi towers that the device can detect, so local wifi signals may be able to pinpoint the device location.

Comment: Yes, something on those those lines...hence the ip address will not really be reliable in our case :(

Comment: See above; if the device can detect nearby wifi signals, geolocation can be achieved.  
EDIT - just noticed your title says "... OR WIFI"!  What kind of crazy Android devices have no GPS or WIFI?

Comment: @JaVAndroid Note that the Google Geolocation API only requires that the device can detect local wifi signatures; it doesn't necessarily have to be connected.